# Why doesn’t my enum work as a method parameter?

Tags: objective-c

I've used `typedef` `enum` in the past with method parameters and had no problem, but today I'm having problems...

h file

```
typedef enum
{   eGetVarious1,
eGetVarious2,
} eGetVarious; 

- (double)getVarious:(eGetVarious)eVar:(NSDate*)pDate;
```

an m file

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're calling a class method, and declaring an instance method:

instance method:

```
- (double)getVarious:(eGetVarious)eVar:(NSDate*)pDate;
```

class method (may not use ivars or instance methods):

```
+ (double)getVarious:(eGetVarious)eVar:(NSDate*)pDate;
```

say you want this as an instance method, declare it like this:

```
    - (double)getVarious:(eGetVarious)eVar forDate:(NSDate*)pDate;
```

and if you were in the scope of implementation of an instance method, then this should work:

```
double result = [self getVarious:eGetVarious1 forDate:[NSDate date]];
```

note the reason compiler is reporting an error:

if it has not seen a particular objc selector and you use it, it assumes the undeclared selector's arguments take id (anonymous objc object).

also, enum type should not be promoted to a pointer (although `0` is ok). since the compiler saw no way to match what you're calling: `[objc_class* getVarious:eGetVarious<enum_type> :NSDate*]` it is right, because you should be calling it as:

```
General * anInstanceOfGeneral = /* something here */;
NSDate * date = /* something here */;
double result = [anInstanceOfGeneral getVarious:eGetVarious1 forDate:date];
```

Comment: @Jules: Although he didn't mention it explicitly, notice that Justin has replaced your bare colon before the lowestDate parameter with "forDate:".  Although the bare colon is legal, you'll almost never see it used because it is far less readable than describing the parameter.